# Apache: Don't apply RewriteRule if requested host is a IP address

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, ip

How doesn't Apache apply an RewriteRule if the requests isn't the normal domain name but instead the server IP?

Current rules (to make domain just accessible without the `www`):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I tried already to add `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^123.321.123.321$ [OR]` but it seemed not to work.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the server config file, this works for me (setting it in httpd.conf):

```
<Location />
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^123.123.123.123$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mainsite.example.com/ [L]
</Location>
```

If I visit the site by IP address, it isn't rewritten.  If I use (eg.) `http://mainsite.example.com`, the address is rewritten (to include the `www.`). The `[L]` (when used in httpd.conf) stops rewrite processing there (instead of now trying to rewrite the new address).

In there you can also have

```
ServerName www.mainsite.example.com
ServerAlias mainsite.example.com
ServerAlias www.mainsite
ServerAlias mainsite
ServerAlias 123.123.123.123
```

so that people can use any of those addresses (the 2nd and 3rd aliases let internal users omit the domain), instead of rewriting to force or add `www`.